# Cross Merging Table Columns and Row in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there any way to do crossly merging  columns and row of a html table, (like red color area of below shown image.)

[image]

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: have you tried anything? code....

Comment: i was clueless..! actually my intension is to achive this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139464/wrapping-text-around-image-without-using-float-align-property

Comment: for that y do u want to use tables?????

Comment: this way of using table, its just my guess work.. because my real goal is --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139464/wrapping-text-around-image-without-using-float-align-property

Comment: This is called an xy problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

```css
<style>
#div{
    width: 600px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
#div #div1{
    background-position: left;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color:black;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="div">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the one you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/Ht7yY/

This CSS is required for the image to float

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. but i want to achive this without using Float:left property.. for more details check my original question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139464/wrapping-text-around-image-without-using-float-align-property?lq=1